# update/modify formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, reference

I have multiple sheets that should have references to another sheet.
For example cell B3,sheet AC:  `=Inlife!G4`. Now I create two new sheets AC (2) and Inlife (2), the  reference for B3,sheet AC (2) should be:
 `=Inlife (2)!G4`

I have tried many variations of the replace option but so far all that I managed to do was remove the formula and leave a value or blank cell.

```
  Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("AC (2)").Range("B3:B10")
    

    For Each cell In rng
  cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "Inlife", "Inlife (2)")

    Next
```

Does anyone know a way to update all the references/formulas in one go?
(I have tried to just use the search and replace function of excel but that gave me an error about the formula)

[image]

Comment: You have to add apostrophes around sheet's name, because it contains space: `'Inlife (2)'`

Comment: Thank you :)
I knew it had to be something simple but I just didn't realize where my mistakes were

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try:

```
    For Each cell In rng
      cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "Inlife", "'Inlife (2)'")
    Next
```

I would also like to suggest replacing of `cell` variable with `cel`. `Cell` is a range property and it is good to avoid creating such variables. It may create confusions on a complex code...

Answer (score 1):

In the end this worked well.

```
   Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("AC (2)").Range("B3:B10")
    

    For Each cel In rng
    cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "Inlife", "'Inlife (2)'")

    Next
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helped you.

Comment: @Tyler2P The OP is the one posting the answer... :) And what is to be clarified in a simple string replacing? The difference between the question and the answer is using of `Formula` property to deal with the appropriate string to be processed.